# MySQL query/PHP code to generate a table with whole dates of year

Tags: php, mysql

I need a SQL table which contains the dates of whole year.

Is there any mysql query or php code which helps me to generate a SQL table with a row of dates of whole year?

Eg: table1:

```
date           book
01-01-2013
02-01-2013
03-01-2013
04-01-2013
05-01-2013
...
..
...
31-12-2013
```

Hope you understand my question! :)

Comment: Well since you tagged this question with php, just write a php function to loop through 365 times and with a mysql insert.

Comment: @Pitchinnate really sorry, no idea about that :( if you have time, kindly please help me in this..

Comment: You can use the `strtotime()` and `date()` function to construct the dates.

Comment: We don't write code for you on this site, you write the code and if you have problems post it then we help you.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace the echo by a mysql(i) query and php will calculate all dates

```
$Date = new DateTime('2013-01-01 00:00');

$End = new DateTime('2013-12-31 00:00');

while($Date <= $End) {
    echo $Date->format('Y-m-d H:i') . "<br/>";
    $Date->modify('+1 DAY');
}
```

Comment: Simple and easy...cant find this anywhere.....snippet gold...